# how to change permalink for dynamic page without 404 error

Tags: pages

I try to create a single page for multi-users page. In WordPress, create a page with a template name employee.

ex: sample.com/employee/ (no error)

Change link like this sample.com/employee/name_of_employee(404 error)

But we change like this sample.com/employee/45 (If we add a number, no error occur)

how to fix this? please help me.

Comment: Sounds like you should create a custom post type with an archive. Call the CPT "employee", that way `example.com/employee/` will be an archive of them all, and then individual links will be like `example.com/employee/firstname-lastname/`.

Comment: Thanks. I already created CPT as employee. Once I try this link example.com/employee/firstname-lastname/. it redirects to 404 error.

Comment: Did you visit the permalink settings page after creating the CPT to flush rewrite rules?

Comment: But I have another doubt. Using CPT, manually I add all pages? Suppose I have 1000 employees. Have I added 1000 records manually? Runtime employees may add.